# chromium-browser cannot cast desktop to chromecast, immediately disconnects

Tags: chromium, chromecast

Until recently, the chromium-browser was able to cast desktop windows to a chromecast device via the three-dot-menu and then 'Cast...'. This stopped working, but I can't tell exactly when, since I use this feature rather seldomly.

The current behavior is as follows:

- The chromecast device is detected and appears in the menu as a cast target.
- When starting a cast for a tab or for desktop, the menu switches to show that it is casting and the chromecast connected screen goes black, but only briefly.
- Then the casting stops as if I had stopped it manually.
- On a site like youtube, casting of the video still works.
- Current version is 89.0.4389.90.

What I tried:

- I varied  all 'cast' related combinations in `chrome://flags`.
- Looking at all .log or LOG files in `~/.config/chromium` brought up no hints.

Any hints as to how to fix or at least debug this further appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/lyc2zh/linux_casting_instantly_disconnects_from/) and it actually has a solution: In chromium use

- three-dot-menu -> settings
- search for 'accel' and disable 'Use hardware acceleration when available'.